# AWS Secrets Manager : Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql

Tags: quarkus, aws-secrets-manager, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to connect serverless prostgress using [aws-secretsmanager-jdbc](https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-jdbc)
I have below configuration in application.properties

```
#secrets name
quarkus.datasource.username = rds-db-credentials/postgres-serverless/rw/dbuser
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql://${db.host}:${db.port}/dbname
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerPostgreSQLDriver
```

Error I am getting is

```
Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql://dburl
```

I am trying connect via aws-secretsmanager-jdbc, I can connect using getting secrets and using regular connection via jdbc

Answer (score 1):

to solve this I created a bean that reads secrets and a bean that implements `CredentialsProvider`   here is below code looks

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("app-credentials-provider")
public class AppCredentialsProvider implements CredentialsProvider {
    @Inject
    DBSecretPOJO dbSecretPOJO;
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getCredentials(String credentialsProviderName) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(USER_PROPERTY_NAME, dbSecretPOJO.getUsername());
        properties.put(PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME, dbSecretPOJO.getPassword());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Config

```
quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider=custom
quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider-name=app-credentials-provider
```

Comment: Indeed, it worked like a charm! thank you so much sir. Just dont forget to add the dependencies: secretsmanager, sts, auth, quarkus-vault